# The replaceItemAtURL: method fails to remove original moved files in some cases

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am using NSFileManager's `replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:` method to move an sqlite file in the case where it fails to move using the `replacePersistentStoreAtURL:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFromURL:sourceOptions:storeType:error:` method. The file has three component files - one that ends with .sqlite, one that ends with .sqlite-wal and one that ends with .sqlite-shm. All files correctly replace their existing counterparts using the `replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:`  method; however, only the moved .sqlite file is actually removed from its original location. The .sqlite-wal and .sqlite-shm files do replace as desired, but it seems that they are actually copied rather than moved, as those two original files are still in place at the end of their respectful successful `replacePersistentStoreAtURL:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFromURL:sourceOptions:storeType:error:` operation. Everything is happening within the same volume, so there seems to be no reason why copies would be made. Can someone help me to make sense of why this could be happening?

Here is the code. The status message, when later logged, reads:

> Successfully replaced SQLITE file. SQLITE file does NOT still exist in
>   original location. Successfully replaced WAL file. WAL file DOES still
>   exist in original location. Successfully replaced SHM file. SHM file
>   DOES still exist in original location.

```
- (void)moveSqliteFileFromMigrateStorePathToFinalStorePathWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSURL * migrateStoreURL,NSString * statusMessage,BOOL actuallyMovedFiles,BOOL movingHudIsRunning))handler {

    __block NSString *statusMessage = nil;
    __block BOOL actuallyMovedFiles = NO;
    __block BOOL hudIsRunning = NO;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSString *migrateStorePath = [applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppData.sqlite"];
    NSURL *migrateStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:migrateStorePath];
    NSURL *finalStoreURL = [CoreDataController desiredFinalStoreURL];
    NSString *finalStorePath = finalStoreURL.path;
    NSString *fromWalPath = [migrateStorePath stringByAppendingString:@"-wal"];
    NSString *fromShmPath = [migrateStorePath stringByAppendingString:@"-shm"];
    BOOL walFileExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:fromWalPath];
    BOOL shmFileExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:fromShmPath];
    BOOL sqliteFileExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:migrateStorePath];

    if (sqliteFileExists || shmFileExists || walFileExists) {

        [SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor:CPS_DARK_BLUE_COLOR];
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"My App is updating. This one-time operation may take several minutes.",@"")];

        hudIsRunning = YES;

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (sqliteFileExists) {
                BOOL finalStorePathFileExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:finalStorePath];
                NSError * sqliteMoveError = nil;
                BOOL successfulSqliteMove = NO;
                BOOL replacingSqliteFile = NO;
                if (finalStorePathFileExists) {
                    replacingSqliteFile = YES;
                    NSURL *migrateStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:migrateStorePath];
                    NSURL *finalStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalStorePath];
                    successfulSqliteMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:finalStoreURL withItemAtURL:migrateStoreURL backupItemName:@"sqliteBackup" options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&sqliteMoveError];//NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly
                }
                else {
                    successfulSqliteMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:migrateStorePath toPath:finalStorePath error:&sqliteMoveError];
                }

                if (sqliteMoveError) {
                    DLog(@"The error for the SQLITE move: %@",sqliteMoveError.localizedDescription);
                }

                if (successfulSqliteMove) {
                    actuallyMovedFiles = YES;
                    if([NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:migrateStorePath]) {
                        statusMessage = replacingSqliteFile?NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully replaced SQLITE file. SQLITE file DOES still exist in original location.", @""):NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully moved SQLITE file. SQLITE file DOES still exist in original location.", @"");
                    }
                    else {
                        statusMessage = replacingSqliteFile?NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully replaced SQLITE file. SQLITE file does NOT still exist in original location.", @""):NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully moved SQLITE file. SQLITE file does NOT still exist in original location.", @"");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    statusMessage = replacingSqliteFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@). ",NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to replace SQLITE file", @""),sqliteMoveError.localizedDescription]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@). ",NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to move SQLITE file", @""),sqliteMoveError.localizedDescription];
                }
            }
            else {
                statusMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"No SQLITE file to move.", @"");
            }

            if (walFileExists) {
                NSString *toWalPath = [finalStorePath stringByAppendingString:@"-wal"];
                BOOL toWalFileExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:toWalPath];
                NSError * walMoveError = nil;
                BOOL successfulWalMove = NO;
                BOOL replacingWalFile = NO;
                if (toWalFileExists) {
                    replacingWalFile = YES;
                    NSURL *fromWalURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fromWalPath];
                    NSURL *toWalURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:toWalPath];
                    //successfulWalMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:fromWalURL withItemAtURL:toWalURL backupItemName:@"walBackup" options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&walMoveError];
                    //THE ABOVE CODE WAS WRONG, WHICH WAS WHAT WAS CAUSING THE ISSUE
                    successfulWalMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:toWalURL withItemAtURL:fromWalURL backupItemName:@"walBackup" options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&walMoveError];
                }
                else {
                    successfulWalMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:fromWalPath toPath:toWalPath error:&walMoveError];
                }

                if (walMoveError) {
                    DLog(@"The error for the WAL move: %@",walMoveError.localizedDescription);
                }

                if (successfulWalMove) {
                    actuallyMovedFiles = YES;

                    if([NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:fromWalPath]) {
                        statusMessage = replacingWalFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully replaced WAL file. WAL file DOES still exist in original location.", @"")]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully moved WAL file. WAL file DOES still exist in original location.", @"")];
                    }
                    else {
                        statusMessage = replacingWalFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully replaced WAL file. WAL file does NOT still exist in original location.", @"")]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully moved WAL file. WAL file does NOT still exist in original location.", @"")];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    statusMessage = replacingWalFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ (%@). ",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to replace WAL file", @""),walMoveError.localizedDescription]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ (%@). ",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to move WAL file", @""),walMoveError.localizedDescription];
                }
            }
            else {
                statusMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"No WAL file to move.", @"");
            }

            if (shmFileExists) {
                NSString *toShmPath = [finalStorePath stringByAppendingString:@"-shm"];
                BOOL toShmFileExists = [NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:toShmPath];
                NSError * shmMoveError = nil;
                BOOL successfulShmMove = NO;
                BOOL replacingShmFile = NO;
                if (toShmFileExists) {
                    replacingShmFile = YES;
                    NSURL *fromShmURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fromShmPath];
                    NSURL *toShmURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:toShmPath];
                    //successfulShmMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:fromShmURL withItemAtURL:toShmURL backupItemName:@"shmBackup" options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&shmMoveError];
                    //THE ABOVE CODE WAS WRONG, WHICH WAS WHAT WAS CAUSING THE ISSUE
                    successfulShmMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:toShmURL withItemAtURL:fromShmURL backupItemName:@"shmBackup" options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&shmMoveError];
                }
                else {
                    successfulShmMove = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:fromShmPath toPath:toShmPath error:&shmMoveError];
                }

                if (shmMoveError) {
                    DLog(@"The error for the SHM move: %@",shmMoveError.localizedDescription);
                }

                if (successfulShmMove) {
                    actuallyMovedFiles = YES;

                    if([NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:fromWalPath]) {
                        statusMessage = replacingShmFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully replaced SHM file. SHM file DOES still exist in original location.", @"")]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully moved SHM file. SHM file DOES still exist in original location.", @"")];
                    }
                    else {
                        statusMessage = replacingShmFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully replaced SHM file. SHM file does NOT still exist in original location.", @"")]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully moved SHM file. SHM file does NOT still exist in original location.", @"")];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    statusMessage = replacingShmFile?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ (%@). ",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to replace SHM file", @""),shmMoveError.localizedDescription]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ (%@). ",statusMessage,NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to move SHM file", @""),shmMoveError.localizedDescription];
                }
            }
            else {
                statusMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"No SHM file to move.", @"");
            }

            if (handler) {
                handler(migrateStoreURL,statusMessage,actuallyMovedFiles,hudIsRunning);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        if (handler) {
            actuallyMovedFiles = NO;
            hudIsRunning = NO;
            statusMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"No SQLITE files to move.", @"");
            handler(migrateStoreURL,statusMessage,actuallyMovedFiles,hudIsRunning);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to @matt, the problem is solved - for the shm and wal files, the 'to' and 'from' were mixed up. I can't believe I missed that. So now, as I expected from researching online - even though it is not written in the documentation - each file is actually moved, and not copied, when the replace method is successful. With my revised and fixed code, this is the message I now get:

> Successfully replaced SQLITE file. SQLITE file does NOT still exist in
>   original location. Successfully replaced WAL file. WAL file does NOT
>   still exist in original location. Successfully replaced SHM file. SHM
>   file does NOT still exist in original location.

Comment: Unclear what the problem is (especially since you didn't show _any_ code). I don't see anything in the docs that suggests the original file will be removed, so why do you have that expectation? If you also want to delete the original file later, why not just delete it?

Comment: This is one answer on SO. Maybe it was wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606841/477641

Comment: I don’t make a copy because the reason I am using this method in the first place is that some users’ databases are so huge that the preferred method to migrate the databases can’t be used (memory on device will not permit). Copying a huge file could have an adverse effect on memory. I just want to move the files. I don’t want to copy them. The reason I am concerned about the copies left behind is that this seems inconsistent behavior to me, and I am trying to understand why it happens. I need to be meticulously careful at this point, and I want to try to understand what *should* be happening.

Comment: I may be wrong, but at a glance it seems to me that you are using the notions "from" and "to" in the opposite of the way I would use them. So I'm a bit confused about what the goal is. Could you just explain in words where the files _are_ and where you want them _to be_?

Comment: @matt, you just saved my life. I am such an idiot. I had gotten the 'to' and 'from' mixed up for the shm and wal files. Wow. Thank you. Now, everything works as expected, and all three files are removed once they are moved to the new location. You are a life saver. Can you add your comments as an answer?

Comment: @matt after I successfully moved these files (all three) in a couple of user's apps, they are getting the error "The file couldn't be opened because it isn't in the correct format." when the persistent container is trying to load the persistent store. I am at the end of my rope. Can you help?

Comment: Probably not. :( But it's clearly a new question, so ask it as a new question and let's see what happens.

Comment: I think it has to do with the wal file, but I don't even know what to ask, and I'm sure I would ask it in the wrong way. I'm just in over my head with programming in general. Thanks - I know you would help if you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but at a glance it seems to me that you are using the notions "from" and "to" in the opposite of the way I would use them. You may be confused about where you are moving the files *from* and where you want to move them *to*.

Comment: Thank you @matt. Sometimes it just takes an extra pair of eyes and a person who gives of their time to help. I really appreciate all of the help you have given to me and to others on this forum.

Comment: This is what we just did: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging As soon as you tried to say in words what the code was supposed to do, it all fell into place!